# Unable to extract COM information from 1 component

Tags: .net, dll, com, installshield

I am building a install-shield project using install-shield 7, I am getting following error.
I tried disabling DEP but it didn't work.

```
Extracting COM data from 1 component(s)
        Warning: -4354: The build was unable to extract COM information from the file M:\tcent.70_win_20081010\base\mti\dm
m\winclnt\bin\DMCom.exe in component DMCom. Please ensure that the file is self-registering and verify that the self-registration process does not fail.
```

Does anybody have idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have you followed the suggestions in the error message? If it really is self-registering and IS can otherwise extract the registration from it, then the issue might be that there's a dependency missing at build time. If that's Win32, use dependency walker on it at the build location to see if they are all there.

Answer (score 1):

it's just a warning, not an error. And you can build it successfully.
But you need to do some registry work by yourself. you may use a custom action to registry this exe. such as regserv32 or installutil.exe ways.